# PHP array inside an array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have this array and I did a print_r($resultArray) and got these results;

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [invoiceid] => 992 [client] => www [invoicedeliverymethod] => email [date] => 2011-11-04 [enddate] => 2011-10-31 23:59:59 [total] => 103.00 [remainingbalance] => 103.00 [ispaid] => No [isagentpaid] => No [datedistributed] => 2011-11-04 [invoicedcontact] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [invoiceid] => 991 [client] => www [invoicedeliverymethod] => email [date] => 2011-11-04 [enddate] => 2011-09-30 23:59:59 [total] => 103.00 [remainingbalance] => 103.00 [ispaid] => No [isagentpaid] => No [datedistributed] => Not distributed [invoicedcontact] => 1 ) [2] => Array ( [invoiceid] => 988 [client] => Sylvester Services [invoicedeliverymethod] => email [date] => 2011-11-04 [enddate] => 2011-10-31 23:59:59 [total] => 16687.83 [remainingbalance] => -16487.83 [ispaid] => No [isagentpaid] => No [datedistributed] => Not distributed [invoicedcontact] => 1 ) [3] => Array ( [invoiceid] => 987 [client] => Colony Holland Lumber [invoicedeliverymethod] => email [date] => 2011-11-04 [enddate] => 2011-10-31 23:59:59 [total] => 8345.39 [remainingbalance] => -8245.39 [ispaid] => No [isagentpaid] => No [datedistributed] => Not distributed [invoicedcontact] => 1 ) )
```

What I am trying to do it write a foreach loop that gets each one of the [invoiceid]

This is what I have so far

```
    foreach($resultArrayy as $key){
    foreach($key as $value){
        echo $value . "<br/>";
    }
}
```

But that returns this;

```
992
www
email
2011-11-04
2011-10-31 23:59:59
103.00
103.00
No
No
2011-11-04
1
```

for each one (but different data)

Answer (score 5):

```
foreach($resultArray as $value){
    echo $value['invoiceid'] . "<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($resultarray as $result)
    echo $result["invoiceid"];
```

Comment: Really 3 upvotes? Nobody realized, that this doesn't work as expected? That _may_ return `invoiceid` of the last entry _only_ (when you use `$resultArray`)

Comment: Technically it worked for the example given... just not broadly applicable.  Semicolon removed.  Today I am edit-king.

Comment: Sorry, I was tired after a long day, I must have been careless. Thanks @Derelased for fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do

```
foreach($resultArrayy as $result){
    if array_key_exists('invoceid', $result)
        echo $result['invoiceid'] . "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: He doesn't need another foreach loop, and if, he can directly get invoiceid inside first foreach. Check my answer.

Comment: But yasar, O(N) is sooo boooorrriiiiinng.

Comment: @Dereleased I didn't get what you meant by (O)N , I am not a native speaker.

Comment: I was just trying to make an example of other variation for the foreach loop